# Is it possible to set type=module on javascript_include_tag in Rails 7 with Sprockets 4

Tags: ecmascript-6, es6-modules, ruby-on-rails-7, sprockets, rails-sprockets

I've been working on a migration project, upgrading Rails 5 to Rails 7. We decided to keep with Sprockets because it is a rather large application and moving over to the new toolset would create a lot more work than we can afford right now.

Everything seems to run fine (all the tests pass at least), but when I fire up the browser, I am getting this error message in the console:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'` which is coming from `application.js`

I read that this can be resolved by setting the `type=module` of the `<script>`.

Is that possible to do? I don't see anything in the documentation for the `javascript_include_tag`.

My understanding is that ES6 support is included in Sprockets 4, so I'm not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any other specified options will be treated as HTML attributes for the script tag.

*https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-javascript_include_tag*

```rb
<%= javascript_include_tag "application.js", type: :module %>
```

---

To transpile ES6 you need to add `gem "babel-transpiler"` and use `.es6` extension instead of `.js`.

*https://github.com/rails/sprockets?tab=readme-ov-file#es6-support*